# Make the default Country India or some others

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

when I am adding shipping address the default country is United States. How can I make it India?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Goto Store >> Configuration >> General >> Country Option and chang
>   Default Country

[image]

Comment: If I want to add a default Zip code, is this possible?

Comment: you can do it by jquery or ask another question i wll show by php